# Creating and then writing to a file

Tags: python-2.7

So I want to read in a text file and then use some of that to write to another file that doesn't exist in the same directory.  So for instance if I have a file named text.txt, I want to write a script that reads it and then creates another file, text2.txt which has some of its contents determined by what was in text.txt.

To read the file I'm using the command,

```
with open(inpath, 'r') as f:
    ...
```

But then what is the preferred way to create a new file and start writing to it?  If I had to guess, I'd think it would be

```
with open(inpath, 'r') as f:
    outtext = open(outpath, 'w')
    ...
```

where the variable outpath stores the directory of the file to be written.  If I understand all this correctly, if the directory outpath happens to exist, running this script would destroy it or at least append to it.  But if it doesn't exist, then Python would create the file.  Is that accurate?  And is there a better, more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe `inpath` and `outpath` are absolute paths. So you cannot do:

```
with open(inpath, 'r') as f:
    ...
```

It will throw `IOError` exception. `open` method expects a file path, but since you are providing path to a directory, exception occurs. The same applies to `outpath` also. Now Lets assume values of `inpath` and `outpath` as:

```
input_path = '/Users/avi/inputs'
output_path = '/Users/avi/outputs'
```

Now, to read a file, you could do:

```
input_file_path = os.path.join(input_path, 'input.txt')
```

The `input_file_path` will be now `/Users/avi/inputs/input.txt`

and to open this:

```
with open(input_file_path, 'r') as f:
    ...
```

Now coming to second question, yes, if file already exists python will overwrite. If it does not, it creates a new one. So you can first check whether file exists or not. If it does, then you can create a new one:

```
output_path_file = os.path.join(output_path, 'output.txt')

if os.path.isfile(output_path_file):
    # file already exists
    # do something else like create another file
    output_path_file = os.path.join(output_path, 'new_output.txt')

# now write to output file
with open(output_file_path, 'w') as f:
    ...
```

Comment: Well, I wasn't really having problems with the file path issue--I was using inpath and outpath as file paths.  My main concern was that it seemed awkward that I would use the "with open(inpath, 'r') as f:" structure and then inside of that use the 'outfile = open(outpath, 'a')' structure.  It seemed like there should be a better, more pythonic way.

Comment: Nope, it is fine. I don't see any issues with that